# Bluetooth transfer problem with big files

Tags: bluetooth

I want to send some data from an Arduino Mega to an android device via bluetooth (HC-06). I have installed some sensors whose values are frequently written in an SD card. Every time a new string line is added in a text file of the SD card. This is the format of the line

```
27/5/2015,11:55:00,34.00,27.00,42.50,26.80,47.80,26.00,24.62,24.12,26,0,0,708,1023,1023,1023,1023,10.5,10.5,10.5,10.5
```

and this is part of the code. I send from a bluetooth terminal the string "download" and after that the text file is opened and every line is readed and sent to the android device via bluetooth.

```
void loop(void){  
    while(Serial1.available()) {
       character = Serial1.read();
       content.concat(character);
     }

if (content == "download") {
    Serial.println(content);
    content = "";
    read_from_SD_Card();
    }
    ........................
    ........................
    ........................
}


void read_from_SD_Card(){
    myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
    if (myFile) {
        Serial1.println("test.txt:");

        while (myFile.available()) {
            Serial1.write(myFile.read());
      }
      myFile.close();
    } 
else {
  Serial1.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}
```

The problems are:

- the data are downloaded only after an upload of the sketch has been done. (I can't upload the sketch once and download the data from time to time)
- No more than 10-20 lines can be downloaded. With bigger files the downloading seems to slow down and finally stops after a few lines.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is a String class heap-fragementation issue (again). To test this you could sending a fixed string buffer (vector of characters, "Hello world" :). Do not use String and SD/FAT in the test. Just send a large number of lines with dummy data.

If this works replace the String usage with a character buffer. Fill it from the SD file (buffer size at a time) and write to Serial.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
String content;
void loop()
{  
    while(Serial1.available()) {
       character = Serial1.read();
       content.concat(character);
     }

if (content == "download")
{
    Serial1.println(content);
    content = "";
    read_from_SD_Card();
    }

........................
    ........................
    ........................
}//end of loop()


read_from_SD_Card(){
    myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
    if (myFile) {
        Serial1.println("test.txt:");

        while (myFile.available()) {
            Serial1.print(myFile.read());
      }
      myFile.close();
    } 
else {
  Serial1.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
  Serial1.readString()//to flush the serial buffer.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed Serial.write() to Serial.print() and added Serial.readString() in order to flush the buffer, but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@user3060854 -- were you able to resolve this? A higher baud rate for communicating with the HC bluetooth module can help with your speed/slowdown problem. But have noticed baud rates above 115200 dont work well. I believe the problem is the receiver baud rate %error, which should not happen at 250k baud. But I havent figured out how to set a baud rate of 250k in the BT module. The question with details is here ---  [Setting non-standard baud rate (250k) for the HC-05 bluetooth module](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18132/setting-baud-rate-of-250k-for-the-hc-05-bluetooth-module)